# source code for logout.php with pdo connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to php, i have been created simple employee register and login form.

This my code:

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo 'Welcome!', '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="login.php">Login</a><br />
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>';
}
?>
```

register.php:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        require 'db.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO emptable (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);

        if($query->execute()){
            header("Location: index.php");
        } else{
            echo 'ERROR';
        }
    }
?>
```

db.php:

```
<?php
    function dbConnect(){
        try{
            $username = 'root';
            $password = '';
            $conn = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=empreg;", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $conn;

        }   catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'ERROR', $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

login.php:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        require 'db.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM emptable WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);
        $query->execute();

        if($row = $query->fetch()){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

According to my above, how can i create logout.php? I am blank.

Can anyone help me?

For secure processing, i had chosen these source code from online.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click on your folder -> new file -> logout.php and you have created the file?!

Comment: You just need to look at how to destroy the session, and possibly place a confirmation link, or dialog into the page to confirm.

Comment: First `unset()` your `sessions vars`, than make `$_SESSION[]` an empty array. Then I would do `session_destroy();`

Comment: Doesn't look very secure to me. You should salt and hash your passwords: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two following functions to clear session details:

```
<?php
    // remove all session variables
    session_unset(); 

    // destroy the session 
    session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Another way of doing it is just using

```
// make sure you don't do unset($_SESSION);
unset($_SESSION['username']); 

session_destroy();
```

Comment: *cough* [Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) *cough*

Comment: from your code, it shows something like this: "Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in C:\xampp\htdocs\selva\php\register\logout.php on line 6"

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show what you have written so far for logout.php?

Comment: then i use, session_start();$_SESSION = array();              
                if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
                        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');}session_destroy(); redirect_to("login.php?logout=1");.. it shows fatal error: undefined function redirect_to

Comment: Maybe because you don't have it declared anywhere? Is that the whole logout.php file? I.e. no included no anything?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer (the original one) to include the whole logout.php file you currently have? That would make it much easier